# How to render JFreeChart in Play framework

Tags: playframework, jfreechart

Problem: does not allow me to `renderBinary`. The method `renderBinary(InputStream)` in the type `Controller` is not applicable for the arguments (`JFreeChart`).

I have this controller:

```
public static void index() {

    // create a dataset...Default

    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

    dataset.setValue("Category 1", 43.2);
    dataset.setValue("Category 2", 27.9);
    dataset.setValue("Category 3", 79.5);

    // create a chart...
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
            "Sample",
            dataset,
            true,
            true,
            false
    );

    List<User> usersA = Department.getUsersA();
    List<User> usersB = Department.getUsersB();


    render(usersA, usersB, chart);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an Img to return.  JfreeChart is not an image.

Also, you need to create a single controller to return the image.  You cannot return the image in a normal render result.

So you'd have a controller like, renderChart(String chartId){ .... make the chart ... renderBinary(img); }

Here code that creates an image from JFreeChart (from http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=113 )

```
JFreeChart chart = createChart(); 
... 
BufferedImage img = draw( chart, width, height ); 
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 
JPEGImageEncoder encoder = 
JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out); 
JPEGEncodeParam param = 
encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(img); 
param.setQuality(1.0f,true); 
encoder.encode(img,param); 
out.close(); 

protected BufferedImage draw(JFreeChart chart, int width, int height) 
{ 
BufferedImage img = 
new BufferedImage(width , height, 
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics(); 
chart.draw(g2, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height)); 
g2.dispose(); 
return img; 
}
```

Comment: and if i whant a gantt chart? that can not be a image :(

Comment: if you want to make an interactive JFreeChart component in your view, you're looking at applets.  (and these days, most people would prefer Javascript components - a few years ago Flash - a few years before that Applets) - Although I worked in a company that (even to this date) deploys Java via the Applet mechanism.

Comment: I build web-based scheduling software, free free to get in touch: intellecti.ca - happy to suggest technology for free even happier if there could be paid work!  :)